# R data.table: using %like% with setkey

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the data.table package and have a data table `dt` with two columns: `result` and `moves`. I want to get the count of times where `result` is "1-0" and `moves` contains "W1.e4". This can be done as follows:

`nrow(dt[result == "1-0" & moves %like% "W1.e4"])`

I am using the `setkey` function of data.table as follows:

`setkey(dt,result,moves)`

However, now trying to write the above command as follows:

```
dt[.("1-0", %like% "W1.e4")]
```

Results in the error:

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "dt[.("1-0", %like%"

When using `setkey` in data.table how should a command be written to include `%like%`?

Comment: You can't do a fuzzy join (yet) in data.table, hence your syntax is incorrect. Why are you trying to do this is the first place? Whats wrong with your initial attempt? BTW, there is nothing fancy in `%like%`- it's just a simple base R `grep`/`grepl` wrapper, so don't expect it to be optimized or anything.

Answer (score 2):

As David points out, that's not exactly how the `%like%` operator works; `x %like% y` will return a `logical` vector with the same length as `x` (examine `` print(`%like%`) ``).

You might try the following instead:

```
dt[.('1-0', grep('W1.e4', unique(moves), value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))]
```

This latter will return the actual *values* of `moves` that contain `W1.e4`.

Comment: Re OP wanting to get the "count of times" this happens, maybe `DT[whatever, .N, nomatch=0]`?